# Using a Custom Authentication/Authorization attribute for an action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity, custom-attributes

We have a website that uses ASP Identity and works great with the [Authorize] attribute sprinkled on all the appropriate classes.

What i'm looking to do is create a separate authentication system for a specific set of actions.  It's a page that isn't exactly anonymous, but can be viewed if a PIN is entered correctly.

I started looking into Authentication/Authorization attributes and got to a point where it redirects to my PIN entry page if not authenticated.

So I guess what i'm asking is how do I authenticate a virtual user (aka: not in the database) to be able to access those pages after entering in the correct PIN?

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own version of the [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) by inheriting from it and overriding the [`AuthorizeCore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method.

```
public class PinAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly string _password;

    public PinAuthorizeAttribute(string password)
    {
        _password = password;
    }
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //Check if user has entered the correct PIN, perhaps
        //by keeping the PIN in the Session
        if(Session["PIN") == _password)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now add it to your action method:

```
[PinAuthorize("1234")]
public ActionResult ProtectedIndex()
{ 
    //snip
}
```

Comment: Note I type this code from memory but it should mostly work! Also the password is hardcoded, you may want to get it from a database or config file for example.